# How to choose mosfet for DC AC flyback

Tags: mosfet, flyback

I am working on dc ac flyback [image]
We have got 35 Volts for the Panel and the grid 120 volts (RMS) 170 V, 60 HZ
I am trying to choose the right mosfet, I need for M1 S1 S2 ( after the diode D1 and d2).
Idealy I want to control each switch with this driver [FOD 8318](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FOD8318-221550.pdf)

It is quite vague (like fog), in the net,  with which parameters I need to choose to select my mosfest.

IN addition I have voltage and current strees
M1 :68 V for 28 A.
S1 and S2 340 v.

Comment: Are you seriously going to hook that up to the mains?

Comment: You do realize that without mains sensing/dropout/anti-islanding/synchronization, that circuit will be 100% ILLEGAL to connect to mains **anywhere**, correct?

Comment: Don't worry about that, I am a student just doing a project in a lab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select your mosfet based on on the max voltage, current, rdson and timing requirements to name a few. Find the max voltage at that node and the max current that will flow through the part. Then go on a distributor site and find a mosfet that will work.

As far as your circuit goes, a mosfet will not work to switch the input transformer because it can't handle the negative current (usually mosfets come with reverse protection diodes) when the voltage goes into the low part of the cycle. You need a triac, or relay or something that can handle the reverse votlage.

Comment: for you for D1 or D2 should I use a triac ? I think I will use a rectifier diode what Do you think about that ?